# Windows 7 unable to shutdown cause of Swing application

Tags: java, windows, swing

We have **a Swing app**. The problem is that `Windows 7` is unable to shut down - message "There are programs still running in the background" is appears and the only way to shutdown Windows is to press Force button.

We have shutdownHook handler it it kills everything we need to kill, but... 
Also profiler shows 2 deadlocks in native `JVM` methods:

```
AWT-EventQueue-0 <--- Frozen for at least 12s
sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.nativeHandleEvent(AWTEvent)
sun.awt.windows.WComponentPeer.handleEvent(AWTEvent)
sun.awt.windows.WWindowPeer.handleEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager.redispatchEvent(Component, AWTEvent)
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.typeAheadAssertions(Component, AWTEvent)
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent, Object)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue, AWTEvent, Object)
java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()<2 recursive calls>
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()<2 recursive calls>
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.SentEvent.dispatch()
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager$DefaultKeyboardFocusManagerSentEvent.dispatch()
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.sendMessage(Component, AWTEvent)
java.awt.DefaultKeyboardFocusManager.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent)
java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent, Object)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue, AWTEvent, Object)
java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()<2 recursive calls>
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()<2 recursive calls>
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.SequencedEvent.dispatch()
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(AWTEvent, Object)
java.awt.EventQueue.access$400(EventQueue, AWTEvent, Object)
java.awt.EventQueue$2.run()<2 recursive calls>
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.awt.EventQueue$3.run()<2 recursive calls>
java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext)
java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(PrivilegedAction, AccessControlContext, AccessControlContext)
java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(AWTEvent)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(int)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(int, Conditional, EventFilter)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(int, Conditional, Component)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(int, Conditional)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Conditional)
java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run()



Thread-1 <--- Frozen for at least 12s
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.shutdown()
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit.access$200(WToolkit)
sun.awt.windows.WToolkit$2$1.run()
java.lang.Thread.run()
```

Does anyone knows what could be a reason?

Comment: have you tried on other OS, like windows xp, any kind of GNU/Linux ?

Comment: @RamonBoza Everything is ok on xp

Comment: Is this a WebStart Application?

Comment: @keuleJ No. It's a common desktop application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you call `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait` in your shutdown hook, it will deadlock. Likewise if you try to show any new windows. Probably most GUI access is dangerous. From the documentation for [`addShutdownHook`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#addShutdownHook%28java.lang.Thread%29):

> Attempts to use other thread-based services such as the AWT event-dispatch thread, for example, may lead to deadlocks.

I'm guessing that's what's happening, though it might be helpful to see the code for your shutdown hooks. What is it that you need to "kill"?